# Memory Usage/Allocation in R

Tags: r, memory

I'm running R to handle a file which is about 1Gb in size, filtering it into several smaller files, and then trying to print them out. I'm getting errors like this at different points throughout the process:

```
**Error: cannot allocate vector of size 79.4 Mb**
```

A vector of this size should be a non-issue, with how much memory I /should/ be working with. My machine has 24Gb of memory, and the overwhelming majority of that is still free, even when the R environment with these large objects in it is up and running, and I'm seeing the error above.

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24213       2134      22079          0         55        965
-/+ buffers/cache:       1113      23100
Swap:        32705          0      32705
```

here is R's response to gc():

```
corner      used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells    673097   18.0    1073225   28.7    956062   25.6
Vcells 182223974 1390.3  195242849 1489.6 182848399 1395.1
```

I'm working in Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

here are some specs from the machine I'm using:

```
i7-3930K 3.20 GHz Hexa-core (6 Core)12MB Cache
ASUS P9X79 s2011 DDR3-1333MHZ,1600 upto 64GB
32GB DDR3 ( 8x4GB Module )
128GB SSD drive
Asus nVidia 2GB GTX660 TI-DC2O-2GD5 GeForce GTX 660 Ti i
```

this is the object I'm attempting to write to file:

```
dim(plant)
[1] 10409404       13
```

the 'plant' object is of the class "data.frame". here is one of the lines of code that prompts the error:

```
write.table(plant, "file.txt", quote=F, sep="\t", row.names=T, col.names=F)
```

Any help on solving this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, that error message means that R has, in fact, filled up nearly all your RAM and needs _another_ 79mb that it can't find. That is a common confusion.

Comment: Quite possibly, you are running inefficient code that is fragmenting your memory. Although you have a lot of memory left, R is unable to find a contiguous space in memory for a small vector of 79.4 Mb. The most likely culprit is a construct that incrementally increases the size of a matrix or data.frame as in `for (i in ...){ data <- rbind(data, ...) }`. Do you have something like that in your code?

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit build of R?

Comment: @James: Are there 32 bit builds of R on Ubuntu?

Comment: @DWin From CRAN: R packages for Ubuntu on i386 and amd64 are available for all stable Desktop releases of Ubuntu until their official end of life date.

Comment: @James: Thanks. I had erroneously developed the notion that all Linux was 64-bit by now.

Comment: Thanks @joran, that's helpful.

Comment: @James I'm using a 32-bit build of R (i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)), and my R version is 2.14.1

Comment: @flodel I'm not using the rbind function, nor are there any loops in my code. All I need to do to produce the error is to try to print out the object 'plant'.

Comment: @ovon Then switch to the 64-bit build, as the 32-bit on is limited to 3Gb and memory fragmentation can mean that you can appear to run out sooner.

Comment: thank you @James, I hadn't thought about the fact that 32-bit OSs and apps would have a 4Gb memory limit (or less)

Answer (score 0):

Tries with memory.limit() function!

```
-
memory.limit(2000)
-
```

Comment: Using Windows 7 with 90Gb RAM I can't get memory.limit() to go above 3583. Is it possible?